# How do I target all index numbers in an array instead of just one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a line of Javascript that is meant find all the HTML elements with the class "OldClassName" and replace their class with "NewClassName" however this line of code only replaces the first instance in the resulting array because of index [0]. How would I replace all the instances of "OldClassName" at once?

```
document.getElementsByClassName("OldClassName")[0].className = "NewClassName";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and loop over each selected element and change the class like below.

If you want to add use `ele.classList.add(<classname>)` and similarly `ele.classList.remove(<classname>)` to remove one.

(This one replaces all the class names with the `new`)

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".old")
elements.forEach(ele => {
  ele.classList = "new"
})
```

```css
.old {
  background: red;
}

.new {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="old">1</div>
<div class="old">2</div>
<div class="old">3</div>
<div class="old">4</div>
<div class="old">5</div>
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

One way could be with a simple loop:

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("OldClassName");
for (let element of elements) {
    element.className = "NewClassName";
}
```

If you want to avoid removing any other classes on the element:

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("OldClassName");
for (let element of elements) {
    element.classList.remove("OldClassName");
    element.classList.add("NewClassName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run for loop on the elements list length and change the class using `classList` and `add`, `remove` to change the class.

With the for loop you define an iterator `i` and then use that as your `key` to target each element in the list.

```js
let className = document.querySelectorAll(".OldClassName");
for(let i = 0; i < className.length; i++){
   className[i].classList.add('NewClassName');
   className[i].classList.remove('OldClassName');
}
console.log(className);
```

```html
<div class="OldClassName"></div>
<div class="OldClassName"></div>
<div class="OldClassName"></div>
<div class="OldClassName"></div>
<div class="OldClassName"></div>
<div class="OldClassName"></div>
```

Another way is to define your class in CSS and use toggle with a function. This would keep the old class and only add it on event handler and remove it on event handler.

```js
function changeColor() {
  var element = document.querySelectorAll(".OldClassElement");
  for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    element[i].classList.toggle("NewClassElement");
  }
}
```

```css
.OldClassElement {
  color: red;
}

.NewClassElement {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="OldClassElement">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
<div class="OldClassElement">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
<div class="OldClassElement">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>
<div class="OldClassElement">
  This is a DIV element.
</div>

<button onclick='changeColor()'> click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to achieve this.

```
let classToChange = document.querySelectorAll(".oldClass");

for(let i = 0; i < classToChange.length; i++)
{
    classToChange[i].className = "newClass";
}
```

Note this will delete all other classes in the element. Several other answers address that as I type this edit out. :)

Answer (score 0):

From MDN

> The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns an
>   array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given
>   class name (s)

In your case the relevant part is `returns an array-like object of all child elements` this means that in order to manipulate all these elements you must iterate on each one of them, as you have used the `getElementsByClassName` method you must iterate using `for`, but you can get the same result of elements using the `document.querySelectorAll` method but you have the advantage that you can use some methods of `array` like `forEach` in the example that makes your code more compact.

Please take a look at the following example

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", toggle);

function toggle() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".old-class-name")
    .forEach((element) => element.classList.toggle("new-class-name"));
}
```

```css
.old-class-name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.new-class-name {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="old-class-name">Item 1</li>
  <li class="old-class-name">Item 2</li>
  <li class="old-class-name">Item 3</li>
  <li class="old-class-name">Item 4</li>
  <li class="old-class-name">Item 5</li>
</ul>

  <button>Toggle</button>
```

See

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach